# Is data locality guaranteed for kafka high-level consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, local

Kafka introduced a new High-Level Consumer API and old `SimpleConsumer`  is now deprecated.
However, the docs lack information about data locality guarantees.
With SimpleConsumer it was obvious that data was read only from one broker.

What about new API? E.g. if I have 2 servers with a broker and a consumer on each, is there a way to force local data reads? Or each consumer would read from random broker?

Comment: This https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-392%3A+Allow+consumers+to+fetch+from+closest+replica is under discussion. If it's implemented it allows you to choose a broker node using `ReplicaSelector`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But if understood the issue correctly, this wouldn't work if the replica factor is 1 (no replicas for partition)

Comment: If topic RF is 1, then the client has to read from the leader.

Comment: At the link you provided there is a discussion about how to read from closest _replica_. What I need is to read from "closest" (local) _partition_ if there is multiple consumers.